# Fourier-Bessel expansion

Tags: fourier-series, bessel-functions

I am trying to find the Fourier-Bessel series for $f(x)=x, 0<x<2$.
Is it possible to express it in the zero order Fourier-Bessel series? If so, it seems $f(x)$ will bot be zero at $x=0$ as $J_0(0)$ is not zero. So do I need to use the high order Bessel?

And for general condition, how to choose the order the Bessel function?

Hope for response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact that $J_0(0)$ is not zero does not stop you from using zero order Fourier-Bessel series, just like you can expand a function in terms of a sine series  even if they do not cancel at the origin.